# check multiple duplicate value validation error in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to insert a form value into database with several compulsory field ,But before inserting I am wanted to check if any of same value is already exist in database.for this my code is

```
<?php include_once 'header.php';$flag=0;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {  $eid =$_POST["eid"];
   if($eid=="blank") {$flag=1;
  $idErr="please Select E-MITRA";}
  else{
  $sqli="SELECT * FROM emitra_device where uid='$eid'";
  $result1 = $conn->query($sqli);
$rowe=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
if($rowe!=""){ $flag=1;
$idErr=" User ID Already Entered";} }

$miatm =trim($_POST["miatm"]);
 if(empty($miatm) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$miatm)) {$flag=1; 
$miErr="Please Enter Valid  Id"; }
 else{$sqlm="SELECT * FROM emitra_device where m_sno='$miatm'";
  $resultm = $conn->query($sqlm);
$rowm=mysqli_fetch_array($resultm);
if($rowm!="")
{$flag=1;$miErr=" machine ID Already Entered";}}
```

.........and some for 3 more field

//for insertion

```
 if($flag==0){$sqll="insert into *********** "}}?>
   working well
```

// form coding like is...

```
<form id="basic" method="post" name="basic"> 
<select class="select-style gender" name="eid">
<option value="blank">Please Select E-MITRA ID</option> 
 <option value="****">*****</option></select>
  <?php echo $idErr;?>

<p class="contact"><label for="bid">m/s Serial No</label></p> 
<input type="text" name="miatm" value ="<?php if (isset($miatm)) echo $miatm; ?>"/> <?php echo $miErr; ?>

 ........more
```

its working well,  but i know it could be improved .  Its may be like this

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM table where (uid= '$eid' OR ***= '$miatm' OR **= '$**')";

  $duperaw = mysql_query($dupesql);
 if (mysql_num_rows($duberaw) > 0) {.....  }
```

But in this I cannot show to user what he enter duplicate....ID/Mno/etc.
Please Suggest a Better Way

Answer (score 0):

You can still show to user what he entered duplicate. Here is the way:

You don't need to select all filed from table. Just select those 5 field, on which you want to have duplicate check.

Once you have result, you foreach/for loop to check which column meets the user entered value. Whichever meets, that's already entered.

```
$error_array = array();
foreach($duperaw as $this_row)
{
    if($this_row['uid'] == $eid) 
        $error_array[] = 'User ID Already Entered';

    if($this_row['m_sno'] == $miatm) 
        $error_array[] = 'Machine ID Already Entered';
    .. .. ..
}
```

Then show the full array with errors.

Comment: what happened if any field have not value in database..means its have null value then

Comment: Then IF condition will fail, and that field is not the duplicate one. If none of IF condition gets true, then your error array is completely blank, which means, none of the POST parameters entered is duplicate one.